# trocar o texto de uma label com valores de um vetor java

Tags: java

Estou estudando sobre vetores, e quero criar um programa que, ao digitar uma senha(apenas letras) no text field e apertar um botão, o programa iria trocar o texto da label senha pelo o que eu digitei no textfield, mas eu não estou conseguindo pensar numa maneira de colocar as letras do vetor senha no lbsenha

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```java
b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                String s = tf.getText();
                String[] senha = new String[s.length()];
                //letras
                for (char letra = 'a'; letra <= 'z'; letra++){
                    //percorrer as letras da senha
                    for (int i = 0; i == s.length(); i++) {
                        //para cada espaço no vetor adiciona uma letra do txtfield
                        senha[i] = String.valueOf(s.charAt(i));
                        //se a letra percorrida for igual a letra do vetor senha[]
                        if(senha[i] == String.valueOf(letra)){
                            //senha recebe a letra
                            senha[i] = String.valueOf(letra);
                            //trocar o texto do label pela senha
                            lbsenha.setText(senha[i]+senha[i++]);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método `append` da classe `StringBuilder` para ir concatenando novos caracteres, e depois no final setar a string completa no label.

**Exemplo:**

```
StringBuilder senha = new StringBuilder(); // instância no escopo da classe

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
 super.mouseClicked(e);
 String s = tf.getText();

 for (char letra = 'a'; letra <= 'z'; letra++) {
  for (int i = 0; i == s.length(); i++) {
   if (s.charAt(i) == letra) {
    this.senha.append(letra);
    lbsenha.setText(this.senha);
   }
  }
 }
}
```